# Swift / how to avoid app crashes if 3rd party services (f.e. backends) are unavailable

Tags: ios, swift, backendless

I am using Backendless as a backend (BaaS). I have just noticed, that Backendless's servers seems to have an issue at the moment. I was unable to create an new app ID at their console. Accidentally I've noticed, that all my apps crash now during the application's start.

All my apps have the same code in the `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    backendless.initApp(APP_ID, secret: SECRET_KEY, version: VERSION_NUM)
    backendless.messaging.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    application.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    print("token: \(deviceToken)")

    // prepare the token to be saved from <xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx...> to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
    var token = NSString(format: "%@", deviceToken)
    token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(
        "<",
        withString: "")
    token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(
        ">",
        withString: "")
    token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")

    print(token)

    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        backendless.messaging.registerDeviceToken(token as String)
    }
}
```

I have already checked, if reachability is true, but still all my apps crash now, because reachability is true, but backendless is down... **How can I avoid app crashes if 3rd party services are down?**

Help is very appreciated.

My `Reachability.swift`:

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class Reachability {

class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress, {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
    }) else {
        return false
    }

    var flags : SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = flags.contains(.Reachable)
    let needsConnection = flags.contains(.ConnectionRequired)
    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}

}
```

Part of app's crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: XX
CrashReporter Key:   XX
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Process:             DJ Remake [4153]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/567B8C2E-C288-454B-B11C-C35F93FB56DD/DJ Remake.app/DJ Remake
Identifier:          com.davidseek.dj-remake
Version:             1 (1.0.2)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-04-29 12:07:54.54 +0200
Launch Time:         2016-04-29 12:06:53.53 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.1 (13E238)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
0.116172     CFNetwork                  0x0000000181819f30 NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1001
60.589908    CFNetwork                  0x0000000181729a44 TCP Conn 0x154699a70 SSL Handshake DONE
60.884066    CFNetwork                  0x0000000181729954 TCP Conn 0x154699a70 starting SSL negotiation
60.884409    CFNetwork                  0x00000001817cbda4 TCP Conn 0x154699a70 complete. fd: 9, err: 0
60.885311    CFNetwork                  0x00000001817cd2d0 TCP Conn 0x154699a70 event 1. err: 0
61.043184    CFNetwork                  0x00000001817cbda4 TCP Conn 0x1545a8190 complete. fd: 5, err: 0
61.043698    CFNetwork                  0x00000001817cd2d0 TCP Conn 0x1545a8190 event 1. err: 0
```

Comment: give details of the crash, stack trace and exception message

Comment: I'm kinda unable. because Backendless service is back and so i can't reproduce the issue. what i have noticed was, that all the apps froze at the start or have instantly closed right after start

Comment: i know, that there is some way to read the crash logs from my iphone with xcode. but i don't know how, could you help me with that? then i might be able to provide more information

Comment: Open Xcode -> Window -> Devices.
On left side choose your device and then select "View Device Logs". You have all processes there you can check.

Comment: crash log snipped provided. i think `NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1001` gives the crash.

Comment: Yes, error code 1001 represents NSURLErrorTimedOut - that means it couldn't connect to the server and timed out. You should handle / catch NSURLConnection errors to prevent app crash and return some warning message.

Comment: okay yes. that is what i've thought. your idea seems ledigt. but could you provide code?